# How to configure Tomcat as response to DNS request?

Tags: windows, tomcat, jboss, dns

Hope you're all doing fin!

I'm working at a company where the main application is at a web page made with Java. It deploys with Tomcat on a server with Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 O.S. I've recently made some changes on this application, but the development environment is not on Tomcat but on JBoss and the former developers knew how to deploy the development from JBoss to Tomcat, but didn't leave any documentation on how to do that.

My problem is that the DNS server is associated with Tomcat, so my development deployed on JBoss can only be accessed through IP address.

My team and I spoke to the company in charge of the DNS server and it indicated that Tomcat's configuration as DNS response should be made by us, given that this company is only in charge of redirecting the IP without specifying the web server.
In order to solve this problem I have two proposals which I don't know how to implement:
1. Modify the server configuration in order to respond to the DNS server through JBoss, overwriting Tomcat response.
2. Deploy the application made on JBoss on Tomcat server.

I would really appreciate your help with any of these proposals. It is a very important matter for the company.

Thanks a lot beforehand for your help.

Comment: If this is your 'main' application, you really should have someone (sysadmin?) within the company who knows these things. Anyway, both options 1 and 2 are too broad and can't be answered just from the info you provided, and the chances you mess up something by just following SO answer are too high. Can you provision a test server for yourself to try there, and then come back with more specific issue to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hey Dusan. Sadly there is not such a person at my company. I'm still working on that. Thanks!